# Changing XAML property by code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have custom combobox with custom arrow. How can I access this arrow via code and change its size (or make it invisible) x:Name="Arrow";

I have tried something with Product_CombBox.FindName("Arrow") but it did not work, so how do I do this?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Border x:Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="15" BorderThickness="1"  />
        <Border x:Name="Border2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="15" BorderThickness="1" />
        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M 0 0 L 8 12 L 16 0 Z" Fill="Black" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
        </Trigger>
        <!-- <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundDisabledBrush}" />
        </Trigger> -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="True">
        </DataTrigger >
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Do I understand correct that you have `ComboBox` with custom `Template` which includes `ToggleButton` with `ControlTemplate` shown above and you want to get that `Path` in code?

Comment: Under what circumnstances do you want to change properties of this UI element? I'm pretty sure you need a `DataTrigger` with `TargetName`, instead of procedural code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `ToggleButton` is part of larger `Template` for `ComboBox` then you you'll need to first find that `ToggleButton` and then find that `Path`. For that you need to give `ToggleButton` some name, let's say `x:Name="ToggleButton"` and then:

```
var button = myComboBox.Template.FindName("ToggleButton", myComboBox) as ToggleButton;
var path = button.Template.FindName("Arrow", button) as System.Windows.Shapes.Path;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using *`FindVisualChild<T>`* function, like this:

```
private void ChangePath_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Path myPath = FindVisualChild<Path>(MyComboBox, "Arrow");

    // For example, change fill color
    if (myPath != null)
        myPath.Fill = Brushes.Red;
}

private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(FrameworkElement obj, string elementName) where childItem : FrameworkElement
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);

            if (child != null && child is childItem && (child as childItem).Name == elementName)
                return child as childItem;
            else
            {
                childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child as FrameworkElement, elementName);

                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

But this is not the best way to work with UI in WPF. You must use the power of styles: Triggers, DataTriggers, *attached* behavior in order to work correctly and conveniently with UI.

You just have to stick to one rule: whatever side on `View`: change colors, sizes, etc. should be done on the side `View`. Just in time will grow logic and code are quietly going to turn into spaghetti code. Accordingly, further work and changing logic will be difficult.